# ErrorException foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given (View:<path>) laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I've created one to many relationship and when I try to retrieve data I am getting this ErrorException
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given (View: )
i am still learning laravel so i don't know much about it. here's my blade file

```xml
<h1>Car Detail</h1>
<h1>{{ $customer->c_name }}</h1>
@forelse ($customer->car as $c)
  <li>{{ $c['plate_no'] }}</li>  
@empty 
    <p>No cars found</p>
@endforelse
```

Here's my model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'customers';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['c_name', 'email', 'password'];
    public $timestamps= false;

    public function car()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Car::class);
    }
}
```

and second one

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Car extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'cars';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['plate_no', 'brand'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class);
    }
}
```

and controller:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $customer = Customer::find($id);
    
    return view('customer/cardetail')->with('customer', $customer);
}
```

I tried `dd($id)` and `dd($customer)` and it successfully passed id and object. I also tried to pass customer as array. i really can't understand where problem lies.

cars migration:

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('cars', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('plate_no');
        $table->string('brand');
        $table->unsignedInteger('customer_id');
        $table->foreign('customer_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('customers')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        // $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Apparently the customer doesn't have any cars. Either they really don't have any cars, or you need to specify the relationship columns on your hasMany cars, if the cars table does not have a `customer_id` column

Comment: please add a @php(dd($customer->car());) statement to your blade file and let us know the output

Comment: may i see your migrations file

Comment: I have added customer_id column in cars migration. if thats what you are talking about. sorry if i couldn't understand you.  let me show migrations here too..

Comment: @mapawa it says call to undefined method :(

Comment: @WaelKhalifa sure...i added them.

Comment: how about the `customers` migration?

Answer (score 0):

Eager load the relationship in the controller and throw an error if the Customer id is not found.

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $customer = Customer::with('car')->findOrFail($id);
    
    return view('customer/cardetail')->with('customer', $customer);
}
```

Comment: yeah it did work thanks for helping. i was getting another error: Call to undefined relationship [car] on model [App\Models\Customer]... then after php artisan config:cache it worked!